# Updating IronPython variable in scope

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am looking into using the IronPython module in my C# application, but I have run into a stumbling block that I have not been able to find an answer to.

The application will be passing variables from C# to the python script, which I have figured out:

```
var PythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
var PythonScriptScope = PythonEngine.CreateScope();

PythonScriptScope.SetVariable('aVariable', 10);
```

During the scripts execution the variable 'aVariable' is likely to be updated outside of the python script (e.g. in the C# app), can I just call SetVariable on the scope again and it will be reflected within the Python script?

Comment: How does this all execute in terms of threads and execution order? Are there multiple python scripts run on the scope and this is interleaved with some C# work? Is this concurrent? Could you use a .net object to encapsulate (and potentially lock/guard for concurrency issues) instead of a basic type?

Comment: @SimonOpelt Each of the script executions will occur in it's own context (thread), but the variables that are passed in can change during the execution.  An example is that the variable of a list of tasks to execute, if another is passed in it gets added to the list.

Comment: If there are multiple threads you would have to think about synchronization/notification. An object could encapsulate that shared state and ensure consistency and avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: @SimonOpelt If I was to do that can my C# application update variables using SetVariable() whilst the python script is running and for the changes to be reflected in the script?

Comment: You would only set the variable containing an object encapsulating the shared state to have a "reference behavior" and be able to lock/notify on changes. Especially when you are talking about a "list of tasks" you would have issues when your C# thread is reading the list while python is concurrently modifying it and vice versa.